# The passwords is not compares. Yii

Tags: php, authentication, yii

I'm new in Yii and i just can't build a working authorization... The `authenticate()` method in my `LoginForm` model return me error `Incorrect username or password`. Here my code...
components/UserIdentity

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
private $_id;

/**
 * Authenticates a user.
 * @return boolean whether authentication succeeds.
 */
public function authenticate()
{
    $record=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
    if($record===null)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    else if(!CPasswordHelper::verifyPassword($this->password,$record->password))
    //else if($this->password!==$record->password)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
    else
    {
        $this->_id=$record->id;
        //$this->setState('title', $record->title);
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
    }
    return !$this->errorCode;
}

/**
 * @return integer the ID of the user record
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->_id;
}
}
```

loginform model authenticate funcs

```
/**
 * Authenticates the password.
 * This is the 'authenticate' validator as declared in rules().
 */
public function authenticate($attribute,$params)
{
    if(!$this->hasErrors())
    {
      /*var_dump(CPasswordHelper::hashPassword($this->password));*/
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
        if(!$this->_identity->authenticate())
            $this->addError('password','Incorrect username or password.');
    }
}

/**
 * Logs in the user using the given username and password in the model.
 * @return boolean whether login is successful
 */
public function login()
{
    if($this->_identity===null)
    {
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
        $this->_identity->authenticate();
    }
    if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
    {
        $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
        Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

`User` model hash

```
protected function beforeSave()
{
    ...
    $this->password = CPasswordHelper::hashPassword($this->password);
    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

and controller code

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!defined('CRYPT_BLOWFISH')||!CRYPT_BLOWFISH)
        throw new CHttpException(500,"This application requires that PHP was compiled with Blowfish support for crypt().");

    $model=new LoginForm;

    // if it is ajax validation request
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // collect user input data
    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if($model->validate() && $model->login())
            $this->redirect(array('/admin/'));
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

I think i'm using `CPasswordHelper` wrong, if yes, please give me correct example. Thank you

Comment: How did you generate the value that is stored in the `User` table's `password` column?

Comment: Please look at the updated question

Comment: Your `beforeSave` method might be conceptually wrong: if you ever call `$user->save()` without asking the user to enter their password, you will hash an already hashed password again, destroying the original hash.

Comment: Yeah, that's right... how to avoid this? I heard about `isNewRecord` variable, guess i should use it

Comment: I suggest splitting "user-entered password" and "hashed password" into two separate properties - "user-entered password" should be a plain property on the `User` model that is only used in the "edit user" forms, "hashed password" should be saved to the DB. Then `beforeSave` should check if "user-entered password" is not empty and set "hashed_password" to the hashed version of "user-entered password" if so.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that no matter what, you set `$this->errorCode` to SOME value, even if it's whatever is in ERROR_NONE. Then you return `!$this->errorCode`, which should always be false. What is the value of the `ERROR_NONE` constant?

Edit: Found out it's 0. https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/web/auth/CBaseUserIdentity.php

So, try throwing an exception with the error so you can see at what point it's failing.

Comment: The problem on a line $this->addError('password','Incorrect username or password.'); and i just catch this error in login form

Answer (score 0):

Next time i use Mysql Workbench, i should check the database columns... The problem is `varchar` limit in `password` field